# To store my Spanned value in Sql server Android

Tags: android, sql-server, spanned

How can I store Spanned values in SQL server and retrieve from database?(In my program I create a smiley images in png format, In SQL database I can't get smiley images, instead of that I receiving ?????? like this) Can anyone solve my problem or send me a link.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: just save plain text like ":)"

Comment: SQL Server?? Do you mean SQLite?

Comment: No, It was SQL Server 2008